# Get sheets with several

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var numsheets = spreadsheet.getNumSheets();
var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets()[numsheets];
```

sheets return undefined.

How pass variable as parameter in the []?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sheets count from 0  while `getNumSheets()` returns the number of sheets (obviously starting to count "the natural way" from 1...)

In your code simply remove 1 like below :

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var numsheets = spreadsheet.getNumSheets();
var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets()[numsheets-1];// gets the last sheet
```

note that `getSheets()` returns an array of sheet objects, therefor the index between square brackets. Arrays are always 0 indexed, this one is no exception.

`spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]` is sheet 1, `spreadsheet.getSheets()[1]` is sheet 2 , etc

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for getting the sheets to a variable and find the number of sheets, you can try this code.

```
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
 if (sheets.length > 1) {
  Logger.log(sheets[1].getName());
}
```

Hope that helps!